# Showing that an expression is real in some domain

Tags: complex-analysis

I have computed some eigenvalues parameterized by a variable $x$ of a Hermitian matrix, and the eigenvalues must be real. However, I'd like to show this explicitly because it is not clear from the expression:

$$
\lambda = -\frac{2 x}{3} - \frac{(1 - i \sqrt 3) (-12 + 24 x - 40 x^2)}{12 \Delta^{1/3}} + \frac{1}{3} (1 + i \sqrt 3)\Delta^{1/3}
$$

where

$$
\Delta = -9 x + 18 x^2 + x^3 + 3 \sqrt 3 \sqrt{-1 + 6 x - 19 x^2 + 36 x^3 - 62 x^4 + 68 x^5 - 37 x^6}.
$$

Now, if I tell Mathematica to do the following command:

`Assuming[x>0 && x<1, Simplify[ComplexExpand[$\lambda$]]]`

then it will give me the following "simplification":

$$
-\frac{2}{3\sqrt{3-6x+10x^2}}\left( x\sqrt{3-6x+10x^2} + (-3 + 6x - 10x^2)\cos\left({\text{Arg}[\Delta]/3}\right) + \sqrt{3}(3-6x+10x^2)\sin(\text{Arg}[\Delta]/3) \right)
$$

where $\text{Arg}$ denotes the phase angle $\phi$ of some complex number given as its input.

Clearly the second expression is real because $\text{Arg}$ must always give a real number, but I really want to know the steps that it took to get there. I have only a very rough idea and no knowledge of complex analysis so it may be a very basic trick that I'm missing.

Comment: The sine function in the last equation is missing a `)`

Comment: fixed it, thanks